# How to hide an option in jquery selectmenu plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

When I try to remove or hide an option from a select( `$('option').hide()` ) using selectmenu jquery plugin at the same time, it will still shows me those options i wanted to remove. After destroing selectmenu i will see usual html dropdown select and it has options removed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose thath you want to change or remove an option.

You can try that with the demo page 
http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/selectmenu/index.html
By Firebug console or any similiar:

```
$("select#speedC").find("option:first").remove();
//and then you can refresh with 
$("select#speedC") 
.selectmenu("destroy") //destroy the custom select menu 
.selectmenu({style:'dropdown'}); //replace with the new custom select menu
```

It's not the best option, but refresh seems that it doesn't work.

Let me know.
Donato.